# Grant all privileges to all users in SQL view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view called Directors on a SQL database called Theatre. I need to grant all users in this view all privileges.

So far I have this:

```
GRANT ALL ON Theatre.Director '*'@'.\SQLEXPRESS'
```

`.\SQLEXPRESS` Is my SQL host server.

But this returns an error. How Do I complete this task?

Comment: I didn't mean to write mysql, just SQL. I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, UPDATE  ON Theatre.Director TO public
```

all users are member of the "public" group. As for the "all" you should avoid using it since it is deprecated.